# Angular 4 Disable Other Textbox when user enter value in one textbox

Tags: angular, angular2-template

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
   userForm: any;
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  'Firstname':[{ value: '', disabled: false }],
  'Lastname':[{ value: '', disabled: false }],
  'Zipcode':[{ value: '', disabled: false }],
})
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="userForm" >
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input formControlName="FirstName"  (change)="toogle()" />


  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input formControlName="Lastname"  />


  <label for="profile">Profile Description</label>
  <textarea formControlName="Zipcode"></textarea>


  <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

When user enters value in Firstname textbox other textboxes should be disabled
and when user enters in lastname ..firstname and zipcode shouldbe disbaled
when user enter value in zipcode..firstname and last name should be disabled

Comment: i am formBuilder and forcontrolname .. not using ngmodel

Comment: So what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need to do is to literally apply what you've explained to us, just in code.

> When user enters value in Firstname textbox other textboxes should be disabled

```
this.userForm.get('FirstName').valueChanges
  .filter(x => x != null && x != '')
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.userForm.get('LastName').disable()
    this.userForm.get('Zipcode').disable()
  })
```

You can do the rest in the similar way. And don't forget to unsubscribe.